# TCPDF: Severity: Notice --> Undefined offset: 0 in 'tcpdf/tcpdf.php' at line 20373

Tags: php, codeigniter, tcpdf

I am using TCPDF library for generating PDF in codeigniter. I have successfully integrated TCPDF version 6.2.8 library in Codeigniter3. Everything is working fine but with several notices. I tried a lot but not able to catch exact issue.

My codeigniter model method is:

```
public function saveToPdf($html, $pdfName, $QRCodeData) {
        $this->load->library('Pdf');
        $pdf = new Pdf();
        $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, 10); //set bottom margin
        $pdf->AddPage();
        if ($QRCodeData):
            $pdf->write2DBarcode($QRCodeData, 'QRCODE,H', 180, 13, 75, 75);
        endif;

        $pdf->lastPage();
        $pdf->writeHTML($html);

        return $pdf->Output(APPPATH . "cache" . "/" . $pdfName, 'F');
    }
```

Everything is working fine but this code generates notices for undefined offset at many places.

My error log:

```
ERROR - 2017-07-22 15:16:12 --> Severity: Notice --> Undefined offset: 0 /var/www/html/ts-2016/api/application/libraries/tcpdf/tcpdf.php 20373
ERROR - 2017-07-22 15:16:12 --> Severity: Notice --> Undefined offset: 0 /var/www/html/ts-2016/api/application/libraries/tcpdf/tcpdf.php 18853
ERROR - 2017-07-22 15:16:12 --> Severity: Notice --> Undefined offset: -1 /var/www/html/ts-2016/api/application/libraries/tcpdf/tcpdf.php 20227
ERROR - 2017-07-22 15:16:12 --> Severity: Notice --> Undefined offset: 0 /var/www/html/ts-2016/api/application/libraries/tcpdf/tcpdf.php 20373
ERROR - 2017-07-22 15:16:12 --> Severity: Notice --> Undefined offset: 0 /var/www/html/ts-2016/api/application/libraries/tcpdf/tcpdf.php 18853
ERROR - 2017-07-22 15:16:12 --> Severity: Notice --> Undefined offset: -1 /var/www/html/ts-2016/api/application/libraries/tcpdf/tcpdf.php 20227
ERROR - 2017-07-22 15:16:12 --> Severity: Notice --> Undefined offset: 0 /var/www/html/ts-2016/api/application/libraries/tcpdf/tcpdf.php 20373
ERROR - 2017-07-22 15:16:12 --> Severity: Notice --> Undefined offset: 0 /var/www/html/ts-2016/api/application/libraries/tcpdf/tcpdf.php 18853
ERROR - 2017-07-22 15:16:12 --> Severity: Notice --> Undefined offset: -1 /var/www/html/ts-2016/api/application/libraries/tcpdf/tcpdf.php 20227
ERROR - 2017-07-22 15:16:12 --> Severity: Notice --> Undefined offset: 0 /var/www/html/ts-2016/api/application/libraries/tcpdf/tcpdf.php 20373
```

You can see my tcpdf.php on github.com at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vsjadeja/tcpdf-codeigniter/master/application/libraries/tcpdf/tcpdf.php

Please help me.

Comment: post `Pdf` library code.

Comment: If you open the file mentioned in the notices in your text editor and you check the corresponding line numbers, you might get a clue of what's going on. It would also help to get a stack trace so you know what line in your custom code is calling the offending code (no idea how to do that in CodeIgniter). Whatever, my educated guess is that `$html` contains HTML that's either unsupported or even plain wrong.

Comment: @jagad89 library code is available at given GitHub url.

Comment: I am asking for `application/libraries/pdf.php`

Comment: Without the HTML you are sending to the functions, it is impossible to guess. Most probably, you HTML is not valid. Try some HTML validator first.

Answer (score 1):

Was getting a similar error and traced through tcpdf.php trying to find what was going wrong.  For me it seems tcpdf.php needs a link. It doesn't have to be used, just has to have one.  Added a dummy one (to page 1) after AddPage() and error has vanished!

---

// add a page
    $pdf->AddPage();

### $dummy_tcpdf_undefined_offset_err = $pdf->AddLink(); $pdf->SetLink($dummy_tcpdf_undefined_offset_err, 0, '*1');

Answer (score 0):

TCPDF supports only few HTML tags, If you have added another tags which are not supported tan also you will get this severity error.

Please find list of supported tags.

```
+--------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| <marker>     | <h1>  | <ol>     | <i>         |
+--------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| <a>          | <h2>  | <option> | <img>       |
+--------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| <b>          | <h3>  | <p>      | <input>     |
+--------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| <blockquote> | <h4>  | <pre>    | <label>     |
+--------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| <body>       | <h5>  | <s>      |             |
+--------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| <br>         | <h6>  | <select> | <table>     |
+--------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| <br/>        | <hr>  | <small>  | <thead>     |
+--------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| <dd>         | <hr/> | <span>   | <tablehead> |
+--------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| <del>        |       | <strike> | <th>        |
+--------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| <div>        |       | <strong> | <td>        |
+--------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| <dl>         |       | <sub>    | <tr>        |
+--------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| <dt>         |       | <sup>    |             |
+--------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| <em>         |       |          |             |
+--------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| <font>       |       |          |             |
+--------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| <form>       |       |          |             |
+--------------+-------+----------+-------------+
```

I Hope this will help you.